# load external data from MongoDB into Oracle

Tags: oracle, mongodb, wrapper

There is a method to load external data into PostgreSQL via a foreign table(Foreign data wrappers).
By this method we can load data into PostgreSQL from oracle,mysql and others.
The question is that:

Is it a same way to load external data from MongoDB into Oracle or mysql?

Important to note:i want to load subset of the external data

Comment: if there is no solutions for this question, please one of the experts say some things about that.

Answer (score 0):

i have same idea, and found this Hive, try it https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/entry/odi_hive_and_mongodb